# angular linky does not work without protocol

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink

The `linky` filter in angular does not work when input does not have protocol.

**JS**

```
 $scope.website = 'www.google.com';
```

**HTML**

```
 <span>Website: <strong ng-bind-html="website | linky"> </strong> </span>
```

It does not create an link. If i add protocol, then it works. How to create link even when protocol is missing.

Comment: The protocol is how the linky filter recognizes that a link should exist. Without that to signify, a lot of false positives would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution to create your own linky function or you can reference it for a regex which will accept no protocol. Using the regex in the link you can replace the logic inside the linky function in the angular library (file: angular-sanitize.js).

[Angularjs directive to replace text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692640/angularjs-directive-to-replace-text/14693341#14693341)