# AngularJS: How to convert text to linky

Tags: html, angularjs, hyperlink, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

How to convert text `URL` to `linkable`? I have used `angular-sanitize.min.js` (1.2.11). I have been using this version since first deployment.

`angular-sanitize` is working properly for the text that has proper format like for example: if it start with http/https/ftp/email but it is not for www.

I want to display the following text URL as linkable, which are not converted by `angular-sanitize`.

1) www.stackoverflow.com 
2) stackoverflow.com 
3) WWW.STACKOVERFLOW.COM 
4) STACKOVERFLOW.COM

Above `URL's` are being shown as normal text.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize'
      ]);

    app.controller('Controller', [
      '$scope',
      '$http',
      'service',
      function ($scope, $http, service) {
        //calling service to fetch data from service.
      }]);

    app.service('service', function () {
      this.fetch = function($scope, $http) {
        //contact server and get address.
        $scope.httpurl = address;
      }
    };
```

My HTML has the following code

```
    <div id="linky-target">
        <div ng-bind-html="httpurl | linky:'_blank'">
            {{httpurl}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693341/2741980) but did not work.
How can I make above specified format URLs as linkable? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The regexp for urls is hard-coded at [linky.js#L107](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ngSanitize/filter/linky.js#L107). If you would like to support those urls, you  have to find an appropriate regex and may do it like the `linky` does.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put to write like this:

```
<div id="linky-target">
    <div ng-bind-html="httpurl">
        {{httpurl}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And with ng-bind-html-unsafe ?