# how to wrap all matches of given string with html tag and append it to a template of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's suppose I have a string like this:

> Some text 321-ABC some text some text some text 761-DAW some text 612-AOS some text some text 733-OQA

It is passed to the directive scope. Now I want to display whole text with matches for **/\d\d\d-\X\X\X/** wrapped with

```
<span ng-click=someFunction(matchedString)>matchedString</span>
```

How can I do this? What's the best practice?

Comment: What's your goal ? Remove the codes ? Highlight them ? What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: I want to create links. Each of these matches is connected with some specific object. These objects are displayed in another view. After clicking some link (span with ng-click) it should redirect to the object of the given name (e.g. 321-ABC).

Comment: @conrisc first of all your regex would be `/[0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{3}/g` and a method of replacing regex matches in a directory can be found [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693341/8495123) (might want to compile the code for `ng-click` to work with `element.append($compile(item)($scope))` or something similar)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey thanks a lot, that is what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let' say your text is stored in `text`, and your `div` containing the text is called `container`.

The code of your container should be

```
<div ng-model="container" ng-bind-html="parsedText"></div>
```

Now in your code

```
$scope.processText = function() {
  $scope.parsedText = $scope.text.replace(/([0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{3})/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
};
```

This piece of code will replace every one of your codes with a link that you can click.

(I'm more of an Angular than AngularJS guy, so replace the link with whatever allows you to do what you want)

Comment: thanks, but I need to use ng-click and as far as I know it doesn't work with angular attributes because it is not compiled :/  

PS. I don't know why but $1 is not working, it's displayed just as '$1'